# What are the necessary and sufficient assumptions for indifference curves to be convex to the origin?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, utility, consumer-theory

I thought this required (quasi-)concavity of the utility, but can this (e.g. declining MRS) occur with fewer assumptions?

Comment: What do you mean by "convex to the origin". Can you give a precise definition.

Comment: I just mean diminishing marginal rates of substitution, so for example, of the type of an indifference curve from a cobb- Douglas preference specification (i.e y = u/x)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. If you want to have decreasing marginal rates of substitution then you need quasi-concavity.

In order for the notion of decreasing marginal rates of substitution to make sense, you need a few assumptions.

- First you restrict yourself to a two good setting, say with goods $x$ and $y$
- You assume that the utility function $u(x,y)$ satisfies all assumptions, so you can use the implicit function theorem in order to express indifference curves as $Y(x,U)$ being the amount of the second good that you need when you have $x$ units of the first good and want to reach utility level $U$.
- Finally, you assume that these indifference curves $Y(x,U)$ are differentiable in $x$.

Now assume that all these conditions are satisfied, then decreasing marginal rates of substitution is the same as requiring that $Y(x,u)$ is a convex function in $x$ for all utility levels $u$. This is equivalent to the convexity of the upper level sets $A_u$, where:
$$
\begin{align*}
A_u &= \{(x,y)| y \ge Y(x,U)\}\\
&= \{(x,y)| u(x,y) \ge U\}
\end{align*}
$$
But convexity of these sets is identical to requiring that the function $u$ is quasi-concave.